# Event for Notification of chart data plotting update completion using Winforms application development

Tags: winforms

I am adding multiple point series to my chart object. I want to know is there any event for chart on which i can wait after adding my series for confirmation of chart rendering complete, so that i can show some message, till event gets triggered to my user.

Answer (score 0):

One (inelegant and untested) approach would be to add an event handler to the chart's [PostPaint event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.postpaint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and track what order the chart elements are processed by using the [ChartElement property of the supplied ChartPaintEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartpainteventargs.chartelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
private void chart1_PostPaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ChartElement);
}
```

Once you have determined which is the last element to be rendered - and assuming it's consistent - you can then tell when the chart has finished rendering in the same event:

```
private void chart1_PostPaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.ChartElement is [last type to be rendered]);
     // Notify user.
}
```

Edit: [it would appear that the last element to fire PostPaint is the Chart itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26169854/43846)